# Determining which direction to rotate a character in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently having a lot of issues trying to determine which direction is the shortest path between two angles. I am programming a  boid in Unity2D, and I am working on the separation aspect. For context, my current system works by creating a specified amount of gameobjects around the boid (I found that 16 of these work nicely). These gameobjects have their own scripts which draws a linecast to the parent boid, and records it's angle to the player. If the linecast hits a wall, or a boid, it adds the cosine and sine of it's angle to two separate lists that are stored in the parent boid. The parent boid calculates the average of these two lists and creates a vector based on that. The boid gets the angle to that vector, and adds 180 degrees to that to find the direction it needs to head in in order to not hit the object. As horrifically inefficient it may sound, it was the only way I could think to do this, and works well.

Now, what doesn't work is rotating the boid towards that goal direction. I do not want the boid to instantly lock into position, but to slowly rotate. I want this because it adds a lot of variation to the boid's movement. The movement takes the current direction that the boid is facing and moves that way. For the most part, I got this to work with this code:

```
void Rotate()
    {
        if (currentRotation != goalRotation)
        {
            int sign = (currentRotation < goalRotation) ? 1 : -1;
            rotateSpeed = Mathf.Abs(currentRotation - goalRotation) / 10;
            currentRotation += rotateSpeed * sign;
            if (Mathf.Abs(currentRotation - goalRotation) <= .5) //If the current rotation is close, just make it the goal rotation.
            {
                currentRotation = goalRotation;
            }
        }
    }
```

(Angles are based off the unit circle)

I really like how this starts the boid rotating fast, and slows down as the boid reaches the desired angle.
So, this code works, except when the current rotation is something like 350 degrees, and the goal direction is something like 10 degrees. The boid will rotate clockwise, even though the shortest path is counterclockwise. I know exactly why, but have no clue how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've worked on boids before, and reading your implementation honestly left me blinking in confusion (though maybe that's just me being bad at maths). It sounds like an absurdly complicated way to do it. There are much, much better solutions. If you're amenable to change your code, search for Conrad Parker's pseudocode for boids. Or Dapper Dino's series on the "Flocking Algorithm". Or many other articles on the web. There are good resources on this. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to do it using as little research as possible. It's a self posed coding challenge. I'll look up the best way to do it when I get a working boid. Then, I'll fix it, or start from the beginning. I'm just bored.

Comment: Then let me just hint that the "best" solution is much, much simpler, and also much more extensible than your method. Good luck though!

Comment: I tend to over complicate things a lot. But hey, now I have a system that makes gameobjects dodge things. If it doesn't work for a boid, I'm sure I can find a better use for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what `boid` is, but here's the solution:

**Not smooth**

```cs
transform.LookAt(target);
```

**Smooth**

```cs
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetObj.transform.position - transform.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

You can combine `Quaternion.RotateTowards` and `Quaternion.Slerp` to achieve ultra smooth solution.

Comment: Boids are used to simulate things like a flock of birds or a school of fish. If you're interested, here's a cool video about them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqtqltqcQhw.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about Quaternion.Slerp.